# Cannot get projection from raster dataset using .GetProjection()

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I can't figure out how to get the projection info from a raster file using gdal.  I thought my raster had a bad srs so I used a script from # https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html to create a raster with a correct srs built with gdal.  Gdalinfo.py reports a correct srs. This is my code... projection is alway and empty (that should indicate an absent or invalid srs (but this is not the case).

---

New info, code works with gdal python library 2.2.2 but not 3.0.2

```
"""
Created on Sun Oct 25 15:09:05 2020

@author: Nicolas
"""
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648439/simplest-way-to-save-array-into-raster-file-in-python

from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy

# https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html
fileformat = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(fileformat)
metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
if metadata.get(gdal.DCAP_CREATE) == "YES":
    print("Driver {} supports Create() method.".format(fileformat))

if metadata.get(gdal.DCAP_CREATECOPY) == "YES":
    print("Driver {} supports CreateCopy() method.".format(fileformat))
dst_ds = driver.Create(r"c:\temp\gdal.tif", xsize=512, ysize=512,
                    bands=1, eType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform([444720, 30, 0, 3751320, 0, -30])
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.SetUTM(11, 1)
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("NAD27")
dst_ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
print ('srs = ',srs)# this is good
raster = numpy.zeros((512, 512), dtype=numpy.uint8)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(raster)
# Once we're done, close properly the dataset
srs = None
dst_ds = None #srs is file and well georeferenced in Qgis.

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# open dataset try to read srs
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
raster_ds = gdal.Open(r"C:\temp\gdal.tif")
# first try
print("Projection is {}".format(raster_ds.GetProjection()))
# second try
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(raster_ds.GetProjectionRef())
print ('srs =', srs)
# thrid try
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs = raster_ds.GetProjection()
print('srs =', srs)
srs = raster_ds.GetProjectionRef()
# forth try
# from gdal_info https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/gdalinfo.py
pszProjection = raster_ds.GetProjectionRef()
print(pszProjection)
if pszProjection is not None:
    hSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    if hSRS.ImportFromWkt(pszProjection) == gdal.CE_None:
        pszPrettyWkt = hSRS.ExportToPrettyWkt(False)
        print("Coordinate System is:\n%s" % pszPrettyWkt)
    else:
        print("Coordinate System is `%s'" % pszProjection)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results for gdal info
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
# Files: C:/temp/gdal.tif
# Size is 512, 512
# Coordinate System is:
# PROJCRS["NAD27 / UTM zone 11N",
# BASEGEOGCRS["NAD27",
# DATUM["North American Datum 1927",
# ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
# LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
# PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
# ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
# ID["EPSG",4267]],
# CONVERSION["UTM zone 11N",
# METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
# ID["EPSG",9807]],
# PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
# ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
# ID["EPSG",8801]],
# PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-117,
# ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
# ID["EPSG",8802]],
# PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
# SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
# ID["EPSG",8805]],
# PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
# LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
# ID["EPSG",8806]],
# PARAMETER["False northing",0,
# LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
# ID["EPSG",8807]]],
# CS[Cartesian,2],
# AXIS["(E)",east,
# ORDER[1],
# LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
# AXIS["(N)",north,
# ORDER[2],
# LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
# USAGE[
# SCOPE["unknown"],
# AREA["North America - 120°W to 114°W and NAD27 by country - onshore"],
# BBOX[26.93,-120,78.13,-114]],
# ID["EPSG",26711]]
# Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
# Origin = (444720.000000000000000,3751320.000000000000000)
# Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
# Metadata:
# AREA_OR_POINT=Area
# Image Structure Metadata:
# INTERLEAVE=BAND
# Corner Coordinates:
# Upper Left ( 444720.000, 3751320.000) (117d35'52.47"W, 33d54' 9.25"N)
# Lower Left ( 444720.000, 3735960.000) (117d35'49.00"W, 33d45'50.54"N)
# Upper Right ( 460080.000, 3751320.000) (117d25'54.40"W, 33d54'11.75"N)
# Lower Right ( 460080.000, 3735960.000) (117d25'51.90"W, 33d45'53.03"N)
# Center ( 452400.000, 3743640.000) (117d30'51.94"W, 33d50' 1.25"N)
# Band 1 Block=512x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the gdal-dev@lists dot osgeo dot org, I was able to figure that this problem was caused by my Anaconda environment.  Problem was solved by updating gdal 3.0.2 (the highest version I could install using the conda navigator) to version 3.1.4 using conda install -c conda-forge gdal.